# How to resize existing content and add new above with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have a requirement to open a PDF file and - on the first page only - scale the existing page content down so that I can insert new content above the original.

For example, if the first page looks like the following (where the *red block* indicates existing content, which could consist of anything):

[image: A white portrait rectangle with a smaller red portrait rectangle inside]

I would want to scale down the "*red block*"/content section in order to then insert a "*blue block*"/new section above it, like this:

[image: A white portrait rectangle with a small blue landscape rectangle and a larger red portrait rectangle]

Where the *blue block*/section is my new content (it will actually be a barcode centred on the page at the top with the corresponding text centred underneath) and the *red block*/section is the original page content (*red block*/section from the first image) scaled to fit in the remaining space.

Any further pages will be copied "as-is" (no scaling, no additional content). The result will be written to a new PDF file.

I have found hundreds of examples on the search engines, and the closest I have gotten is as follows:

```
        iTextSharp.text.Image bc = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Code128.GetBarcode(barcodeContent, 5), ImageFormat.Bmp);

        string path = "C:\\";
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Path.Combine(path, @"multipageimage.pdf"));
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, @"multipageimage2.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

        float pageWidth = pdfReader.GetPageSize(1).Width, pageHeight = pdfReader.GetPageSize(1).Height;
        bc.ScaleAbsolute(pageWidth / 3, 40);
        bc.SetAbsolutePosition((pageWidth - bc.Width) / 2, pageHeight - bc.Height);

        int n = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++)
        {

            float percentage = 1.0f;
            if (p == 1)
                percentage = 0.7f;

            float offsetX = (pdfReader.GetPageSize(p).Width * (1 - percentage)) / 2;
            float offsetY = (pdfReader.GetPageSize(p).Height * (1 - percentage)) / 2;
            pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(p).SetLiteral(String.Format("\nq {0} 0 0 {1} {2} {3} cm\nq\n", percentage, percentage, offsetX, offsetY));
            PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(p);

            if (p == 1)
            {
                pdfContentByte.AddImage(bc);
            }

        }
        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
```

However, the problem is that the barcode becomes part of the smaller "*scaled*"/"*Red Block*" content and does not attach to the top of the page.

Where am I going wrong?

**Note**: *I am currently limited to using iTextSharp 5.5.9 and cannot currently update to the newer iText 7/8 as I do not have the time to update other functionality using the same library.*

To clarify/simplify, I want to:

- Extract the existing content of the page
- Draw a fixed size block (the barcode and text) at the top of the page
- Draw the original page content, scaled so that it fits, in the remainder of the page under the new block I have added
- Write this as the first page in a new PDF
- Copy the remaining pages to the same new PDF without any modifications

Revised code based upon @mkl's observations...

```
        iTextSharp.text.Image bc = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Code128.GetBarcode(barcodeContent, 5), ImageFormat.Bmp);

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Path.Combine(path, @"multipageimage.pdf"));
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, @"multipageimage2.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

        float pageWidth = pdfReader.GetPageSize(1).Width, pageHeight = pdfReader.GetPageSize(1).Height;
        bc.ScaleAbsolute(pageWidth / 3, 40);
        bc.SetAbsolutePosition((pageWidth - bc.Width) / 2, pageHeight - bc.Height);

        int n = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++)
        {

            float percentage = 1.0f;
            if (p == 1)
                percentage = 0.7f;

            float offsetX = (pdfReader.GetPageSize(p).Width * (1 - percentage)) / 2;
            float offsetY = (pdfReader.GetPageSize(p).Height * (1 - percentage)) / 2;
            PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(p);

            if (p == 1)
            {
                pdfContentByte.AddImage(bc);
            }

            pdfContentByte.SetLiteral(String.Format("\nq {0} 0 0 {1} {2} {3} cm\nq\n", percentage, percentage, offsetX, offsetY));
            pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(p);

        }
        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
```

Comment: I would propose adding the image to the `UnderContent` before adding the **cm** literal.

Comment: @mkl: That has helped; the barcode is now above the original scaled content, however there is a problem with the scaling of the barcode - it is not sizing as I am telling it to (ScaleAbsolute). My page width is 595, and I am calling ScaleAbsolute(595/3, 40) but the Image (bc) still has Height 126 and Width 835. This also means it is in the wrong position.

Comment: *"however there is a problem with the scaling of the barcode - it is not sizing as I am telling it to"* - That surprises me (but I haven't done any content generation with the old iText anymore for a long time). I'd try the `pdfContentByte.AddImage` with the transformation matrix entries, i.e. `pdfContentByte.AddImage(bc, width, 0, 0, height, x, y)`.